# Display and Expressions views disappearing on Debug perspective

Tags: eclipse, debugging

On Eclipse's **Debug perspective**, if I pin the `Display` and `Expressions` views on the panels, they just disappear some time after the debugging - apparently when Eclipse switches the perspectives again from Java/Java EE to Debug.

Is this really a Bug (*or a Feature I didn't get it*) or is it some configuration issue? Is there any directions or workaround to make it work? Pinning them again everytime I get into debug is annoying.

I've been having this issue from quite some time on different distributions of Eclipse (right now on *JBoss Developer Studio 4.0.0.GA*) and on different machines (*Windows*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save a perspective. I would open debug perspective and pin Expressions and Display views to it and save it(Windows->Save Perspective as) as MyDebug .

And it would get added to the perspective's list and if you use it often you should be able to see it on the top right corner all the time.

Comment: Nice workaround! Let's just wait for some new thoughts.

Comment: Just for information: doing that, I had to change Eclipse's Debug action on JavaEE applications. Otherwise, when a breakpoint is hit on a webapp, it would automatically show the default Debug perspective, not the custom one.